# How can I debug a WearableListenerService in Android Studio?

Tags: android, wear-os

I can only deploy either the wearable app, or the mobile app, to my devices. Is there a way to deploy both at the same time while debugging? It's very difficult to debug a WearableListenerService otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build you app using release keys.

> When you're ready to publish your app to users, you embed the wearable
>   app inside of the handheld app. When users install the handheld app
>   from Google Play, a connected wearable automatically receives the
>   wearable app

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#Install

What problems you have with testing WearableListenerService anyway? Works fine for me even if I install apps separately.

Comment: Testing is fine, but debugging is not possible. I can't set a breakpoint in both apps and step through the execution. It's a real pain to keep switching back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uploading and installing your Wear App from console line using adb :
`adb -s <wearable_id> install <path_to_apk>`
You can retreive the ID of your device once connected to adb (via Bluetooth debugging) with
`adb devices`

Comment: Good suggestion, but this won't attach the debugger to the Wear app, so I still can't debug both at the same time.

Comment: Of course you can :) Just open 2 terminals, on one you execute `$ adb -s <werable_id> logcat` and on the other one : `$ adb -s <handheld_id> logcat`

Comment: Or directly on Android Studio, on the console pannel at the bottom, on the tab "devices" you can switch the logcat debugging between your handheld and your smartwatch, but it has proven to be not that efficient. I'm much more comfortable with the terminal :)